How do you convert the damping coefficient to speed dependent drag coefficient (for low speeds)?
I'm trying to understand how to convert the damping coefficent to the speed dependent drag coefficient for an investigation I am doing for school.

I'll assume here that you're dealing with something like a mass-damper-spring system, governed by equation
$$m \ddot{x} + k x = f^e + f^{drag} \ .$$
The behavior of a fluid is usually largely influenced by a non-dimensional number, the Reynolds number $Re = \frac{U L}{\nu}$, being $L$ a characteristic length of the system and $nu$ the kinematic viscosity.
Usually:

for low Reynolds numbers (and thus low speed, keeping $L$ and $\nu$ constant), the drag of a body is linear with the relative speed w.r.t. the fluid, namely
$$f^{drag} = -c u_{rel} = - c \dot{x} \ ,$$
with $u_{rel} = \dot{x} - u^{fluid}$, assuming $u^{fluid} \simeq 0$; in this case, the equation of motion reads
$$m \ddot{x} + c \dot{x} + k x = f^e \ ;$$

for high Reynolds numbers (and thus high speed, keeping $L$ and $\nu$ constant), the drag of a body is quadratic with the relative speed w.r.t. the fluid, namely
$$f^{drag} = -\frac{1}{2}\rho u^2_{rel} S c_D = - \frac{1}{2} \rho \dot{x}^2 S c_D$$
with $u_{rel} = \dot{x} - u^{fluid}$, assuming $u^{fluid} \simeq 0$, $S$ a characteristic area of the body and $c_D$ its drag coefficient in this case, the equation of motion reads
$$m \ddot{x} + \frac{1}{2} \rho S c_D \dot{x}^2 + k x = f^e \ ,$$
that you can formally write as
$$m \ddot{x} + c(\dot{x}) \dot{x} + k x = f^e \ ,$$
with the damping coefficient dependent of the velocity,
$$c(\dot{x}) = \frac{1}{2} \rho S c_D \dot{x} \ .$$


